# Sort a map having arraylist as values based on property in java

Tags: java, list, collections, java-8, hashmap

I have a complex custom object like

```
public class MySortedObject {

 private static class Employee {
        public String name;
        public String ssn;
        
        public Employee(String name, String ssn) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.ssn = ssn;
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Map<Integer, List<Employee>> map = new HashMap<>();
    
    Employee empl1 = new Employee("XYZ", "22DEC2019");
    Employee empl2 = new Employee("ABC", "22DEC2019");
                                                    
    Employee empl3 = new Employee("GHI", "18APR2019");
    Employee empl4 = new Employee("DEF", "18APR2019");
                                                    
    Employee empl5 = new Employee("WXY", "15OCT2019");
    Employee empl6 = new Employee("JKL", "15OCT2019");
    
    List empList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List empList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    List empList3 = new ArrayList<>();
    
    empList1.add(empl1);
    empList1.add(empl2);
    
    empList2.add(empl3);
    empList2.add(empl4);
    
    empList3.add(empl5);
    empList3.add(empl6);
    
    map.put(1, empList1);
    map.put(2, empList2);
    map.put(3, empList3);

}
```

My object is a map of <Integer,List>. The list is having objects which contain a value(i.e. ssn). I want to sort my map based on this ssn value. The order of the map should be "1,3 and 2"

Comment: Shouldn't `map.put(2, empList3);` be `map.put(3, empList3);`? Also can you explain what you mean by "*order of the map should be "map.get(1)", then "map.get(3)" and at last "map.get(2)" i.e. "1,3 and 2"*"?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. Updated the code. I wanted to mention the order of the objects i.e. 1,3,2

Comment: @iota, I want to sort my map on the basis of the "ssn" field of employee object

Comment: `ssn` of all the element of list is same ?

Comment: @Rono Yes...for a single list it is same. It is different w.r.t other list

Comment: Does `ssn` has to be as `String` or can we assume that it is some more specific date related type like `LocalDate`?

Comment: *"My object is a map of <String,List>"* No, your object is a map of <Integer,List>

Comment: @Andreas. Sorry for the typo. Updated the problem statement

Comment: Use LocalDate for ssn field then it will be easy to sort and collect as LinkedHashMap. Like `Map<Integer, List<Employee>> res = map.entrySet().stream().sorted((a, b) -> b.getValue().get(0).ssn.compareTo(a.getValue().get(0).ssn)).collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue(), (a, b) -> a, LinkedHashMap::new));
` [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/rJped7rSw)

Comment: `map = map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getValue().get(0).getSsn())).collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (a,b)->a, LinkedHashMap::new));`

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String dateInString = ssn;
        Date date=null;
        try {
            date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`  _--date sort function_

Comment: `Collections.sort(list, (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Employee>> o1, Map.Entry<Integer, List<Employee>> o2)-> { try { Date d1= stringToDate(o1.getValue().get(0).ssn);
  Date d2= stringToDate(o2.getValue().get(0).ssn);  if(d1.before(d2)) { return  1; }
   else if(d2.before(d1)) { return -1; } } catch (ParseException e) { } return 0; });` Compare function, please do map to linkedlist conversion before this compare fun & list to linkedhashmap conversion after compare fun. You can get your expected output